# Using an empty object as a parameter to a conditional if loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

This is similar to what I have been trying to do,

```
var obj = {};
if(obj){
//do something
}
```

What i want to do is that the condition should fail when the object is empty.

I tried using JSON.stringify(obj) but it still has curly braces('{}') within it.

Comment: Try `Object.keys(obj).length`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and check the length of the array of the own keys.

```js
function go(o) {
    if (Object.keys(o).length) {
        console.log(o.foo);
    }
}

var obj = {};

go(obj);
obj.foo = 'bar';
go(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the object is empty, i.e. it has no properties, using

```
Object.keys(obj).length === 0
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns all properties of the object in an array.

If the array is empty (`.length === 0`) it means the object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Object.keys(myObj).length` to find out the length of object  to find if the object is empty.

working example

```js
    var myObj = {};
    if(Object.keys(myObj).length>0){
      // will not be called
      console.log("hello");
    }


   myObj.test = 'test';

    if(Object.keys(myObj).length>0){
      console.log("will be called");
    }
```

See details of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)